# change the language of iOS app dynamically

Tags: ios, object

i have seen some iOS application that change the language used in the application dynamically, i mean that when the app is lunched the user can change the language ( french, english,...) dynamically; i have searched in internet and i have found anything about this .

Any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write your own version of the NSLocalizedString macro, which chooses a language bundle based on a user preference, instead of the phones locale

Comment: Thanks, do you have any resources to do this ?

Comment: i found [this](http://learning-ios.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/advance-localization-in-ios-apps.html) after a quick search, i dont know how accurate it is though

Answer (score 0):

You have to use localization. Here's one tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

We are using something like the below (inspired by Localize-Swift). Note that you would have to store the chosen language in something else than `UserDefaults.standard` if you are using app extensions. Should be pretty easy to extend with plural support if needed.

After adding the class and string extension below you would call `"key_from_string_files".localized()` instead of the variants of `NSLocalizedString` to get localized strings.

```
extension String {
    func localized(_ key: String, arguments: [CVarArg] = []) -> String {
        return Localize.localized(key, arguments: arguments)
    }
}

class Localize {
    static var storeKey = "custom_current_language"

    class func localized(_ key: String, arguments: [CVarArg]) -> String {
        let string: String
        let lang = currentLanguage()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj"), let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
            string = bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
        } else {
            string = key
        }

        return String(format: string, arguments: arguments)
    }

    class func currentLanguage() -> String {
        if let current = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: storeKey) as? String, Bundle.main.localizations.contains(current) {
            return current
        } else if let preferred = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first {
            return preferred
        }
        fatalError("Could not determine application localization")
    }

    class func setCurrentLanguage(_ language: String?) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(language, forKey: storeKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}
```